# How to populate vuetify select box using data from ajax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to populate a vuetify select box using data retrieved in an ajax call. I am not sure how to populate the select box using this data. The ajax call works an I get an array of objects that I set equal to items. This is what I have tried:

## v-select

```
<v-select
:items="items"
item-text="test"
v-model="client"
label="Choose a Client"
class="input-group--focused"
item-value="text"
></v-select>
```

## Get client Function

```
getClient: function (items) {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/')
        .then(function (response, items) {
            console.log(response.data);
            items  = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    }
```

## Call function

```
created() {
    this.getClient(this.items);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are passed by (value of) reference, which is why when you **assign** `items` inside the `getClient` function, it does not affect `this.items`.

Use `this.items` directly:

```
created() {
    this.getClient();                                   // removed this.items
},
methods: {
    getClient: function () {                            // replaced `function (items) {` with `function () {`
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/')
            .then((response) => {                       // replaced `function (response, items) {` with `(response) => {`
                console.log(response.data);
                this.items  = response.data;            // used `this.items = ` instead of `items = `
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

Important: notice I replaced:

```
.then(function (response, items) {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.items = response.data;
})
```

With

```
.then((response) => {                // using arrow function now
    console.log(response.data);
    this.items = response.data;
})
```

This is important because the `this` (in `this.items = response.data;`) **does not point to the Vue instance when you use `function () {`**, but it does when you use arrow function.

This happens because each `function () {}` has its own context (its own `this`), which could be set to something else. Arrow functions, otoh, inherit the context (the `this`) of where it is declared. In this case, since you are declaring it inside a method, the `this` is the Vue instance. Using an arrow function keeps it. Using a `function()` does not guarantee it (the `this` could be set to something else, which probably happens).

For futher details, I recommend [MDN - Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: I tried this earlier without the arrow syntax, what about the arrow syntax allowed this work?

Comment: I have included additional info about the arrow functions usage. Check it out.